# Source .Rmd in r script

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a source() command for .Rmd files? The thing is I have .Rmd file that produces graphs with some texts. I would like to call this .Rmd file in my r-script that is run every month.

Comment: You can call and render your .Rmd file from your r-script via `rmarkdown::render(input = 'XXXXX.Rmd')`.

Comment: Thanks stefan, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

install the "cronR" package, then in Rstudio you can run this job using cron inside Rstudio to run the file automatically when you desire